# Trouble with installing JDBC for Postgres

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, jdbc

I would like to use JDBC. My code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Properties;

public class test {

Connection conn;

public test() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/tb";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user","user");
    props.setProperty("password","passwd");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
    System.out.println(conn.isClosed());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        test t = new test();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
}
}
```

My soft: postgres 9.1, java 1.7

My try:

```
ziel@gad ~/java/test $ ls
postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar  test.java
ziel@gad ~/java/test $ javac test.java 
ziel@gad ~/java/test $ java -cp postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar test
Error: Could not find or load main class test
```

According to people from google this should load the driver. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `java -cp postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar:. test` under Linux / Unix / OS X

Answer (score 3):

Thats because when you did `-cp postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar`, you defined the jar `postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar` as the only location of your class files and the class `test` isn't in this `jar`. To resolve the problem you have to execute this cmd `java -cp postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar;. test`

Comment: If I do `java -cp 'postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar;.' test` I get the same: `Error: Could not find or load main class test`.

Comment: do you have the file `test.class` in `~/java/test`? why did you use simple quotes `'` in your cmd?

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are using linux os, so try this `java -cp postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar:. test`.
In windows `java -cp postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar;. test`

Answer (score 0):

Execute following on Linux machine

`javac -cp '.:postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar' postgresjavatest.java`

`java -cp '.:postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar' postgresjavatest`

make sure jar file is on same location where command is fired.

Comment: the OP has **postgresql-9.1-902.jdbc4.jar**. Why are you posting this answer everywhere?